Detox iOS Visibility Issues
This line works when run against Android, but fails against iOS with the error below.  How can I identify the problem?
Using Debug View Hierarchy in XCode it looks like there are several layers on top of the textBox (_UITextLayoutCanvasView, UITextFieldLabel, and _UITouchPassthroughView).  But they all look transparent
await element(by.id('FirstName')).typeText('John'); 

Error:
Test Failed: View is not hittable at its visible point. Error: View is not visible around point.
    - view point: {81.166664123535156, 28}
    - visible bounds: {{0, 0}, {162.33332824707031, 56}}
    - view bounds: {{0, 0}, {162.33332824707031, 56}}
    ---
    Error: Error Domain=DetoxErrorDomain Code=0 "View “<RCTUITextField: 0x11899f000>” is not visible: View does not pass visibility percent threshold (100)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=View “<RCTUITextField: 0x11899f000>” is not visible: View does not pass visibility percent threshold (100)}


I have experienced this error only when the screen I thought should be there was not present. So I would check whether you indeed have the correct screen active.
You can also check with the Accessibility Inspector whether that specific view (element) is present and can be selected. As you seem to have layers on top I suspect it can't be found.

I have been facing the similar issue for couple of hours on a button .tap(). I do not why but I just added .tap({
x: 0,
y: 0,
}), and it started working, and I do not know how and why.
